# Are immunity and immune-system genuine synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I doubt that `immunity` and `immune-system` should be synonyms. They are obviously closely related but as far as I know they are not synonyms rather just related to each other.

I'd argue that `immunity` is caused by the `immune-system` but `immunity` itself is not the `immune-system`.

Is it used as the same thing in some medical context that I am not aware about?

Comment: Sure, there's a distinction and it would be better to have both and for both to have decent descriptions, but tag maintenance is last place in priorities for most people. Keep building your rep and once you get to the ability to edit tags, by all means go for it.

Answer (score 4):

A tag synonym doesn't mean "these two words mean the same thing." It means "a question about X is ipso facto a question about Y". Can you imagine a question that is about immunity but is not about the immune system, or vice versa? If these were two separate tags, can you imagine a question using only one tag where the other would not belong?

Historically this site has used stuff-all-the-synonyms-into-one-tag tags like [stools-fecal-matter-poop](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stools-fecal-matter-poop) which I think is suboptimal. But there are some synonyms: consider [dermatology](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dermatology) and [skin](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skin). These are not dictionary synonyms at all. But for the purposes of this site, if your question is about skin, it's about dermatology, and vice versa. That's what synonym means here.

Comment: I semi-disagree:  "*How long does it typically take for an MD to be certified as a dermatologist?*" is not about [tag:skin]; and "*statistical calculation of herd immunity*" is not about [tag:immune-system].

Comment: I think the real issue is whether tag synonyms are intended to relate similar topics or topics with a common audience.

Comment: tags exist to be watched and ignored, and to a lesser extent to get tag badges in. They can also remind readers of important information that would otherwise be somewhere loose in the body - on other sites this might be what programming language you're using, or the country that you are travelling to or asking about the laws or culture of.